# Show that the predicate $y=x+1$ is not definable in the interpretation $(\mathbb Z,=,f)$ where $f$ is a unary function $x \mapsto x+2$

Tags: logic, automorphism-group

I tried to build an automorphism that preserves the equality relation and the function $f$, such that if $l$ is that automorphism then $l(f(x)) = f(l(x))$ and such that if we define $P(x,y)$ to be the predicate $y=x+1$ then $P(x,y)$ won't equal to $P(l(x),(l(y))$.

I couldn't really find one. I was trying to argue that if I define $l(x):= x+2$ then $P(x,y)$ is not equal to $P(l(x),l(y))=P(x+2,y+2)$ then the relation of $y=x+1$ is not the same as $y+2=x+3$ but that just seemed wrong... any hint on the kind of automorphism I should build would be appreciated!

Comment: Why would y=x+1 not imply y+2=x+3? It seems to me it *does* imply it, simply by adding 2 to both sides of y=x+1. I must be missing something... in (Z,=,f) is there not an operation of addition?

Comment: I thought that since its not an a abilian group and the signature only uses Z , =  and f I can say that adding to the equality changes the predicate but I am not sure if its correct...

Comment: Where in your question is there anything about a structure being abelian or not? Something has been left a bit vague in your question (in my opinion).

Comment: I mean I am not saying that I am correct, I just thought given this information I can say there is no adding operation...

Comment: Please don't delete a question and then ask a new question on the same topic. If there is new information to add, just edit the existing question. This will bump it back to the top of the page anyway.

Comment: Noted, sorry didn't know it worked this way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to mse!

I'm not sure why this question is so highly downvoted. It seems clear to me what you're asking, and that you have a good idea of how to attack it and have tried a few things. Regardless, here's some hints:

1. (minor hint)

> Notice that $f$ preserves the decomposition $\mathbb{Z} = \text{Evens} \sqcup \text{Odds}$ in the sense that
>  $f \! \upharpoonright_\text{Evens} : \text{Evens} \to \text{Evens}$ and
>  $f \! \upharpoonright_\text{Odds} : \text{Odds} \to \text{Odds}$ are both bijections.
>  So this means that the even part and the odd part don't interact! Does this encourage you to look at any particular kind of automorphism?

2. (major hint)

> Since the Even and Odd parts of the structure don't interact, there are automorhpisms of the structure that do something different to even numbers and odd numbers. For instance
>
>  $$\varphi(x) = \begin{cases} x & x \text{ is Even} \\ x+2 & x \text{ is Odd} \end{cases}$$
>
>  Do you see why this is an automorhpism? Do you see why it doesn't preserve $``x = y+1''$?

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Didn't think about defining it that way, tyvm!